# Complex SSIS delete Scenario

Tags: ssis

I have two databases on separate servers. Both database has same schema.We need to move data from one database to other in such a way that if record only exist on destination then it should be deleted. I have following scenario to address in SSIS.

Ingredient table holds ingredients against Recipes and each recipe belong to a "Package.

```
Package --> Recipe --> Ingredient
```

Package is top level then Recipe and then Ingredient. We move data Package by Package. SSIS package is already in place that takes PackageId and Move all the Recipes and Ingredients to target database. There is no Package table in Target database because we use this to Package up data for data movement.  Now the Scenario is ,

1. We are moving Package where PackageId = 1
2. Suppose Package 1 has two Recipes and These Recipes Already Exist in Source and Destination But recipes on destination has more ingredient e.g. Source Package 1 has RecipeA and RecipeB. These two Recipes already exist on Destination. But Destination RecipeB has more ingredints. I need to delete those extra ingredients.

I can't use Execute SQL task as Source and Destination databases are on different Servers. Can anyone suggest how this can be done in data flow?

Following design comes to mind.

1. Find All RecipeId's that exist in Package XYZ on SOurce.
2. Compare it with Same Recipes and find out which ingredient only exist on destionation.

   **Source Database**

   **Ingredient Table**

   Id Name RecipeId

   **Recipe Table**

   RecipeId Name PackageId

   **Package Table**
     PackageId Name

   *Target Database****

   **Ingredient Table** 
     Id Name RecipeId

   **Recipe Table** 
     RecipeId Name BundleId

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create an Staging base in the Destination server where you are going to copy the information without look for references, after that you can do the compare directly in the same server.

I hope it helps.